# Multiple returns versus Exit for

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, coding-style, return-value

I have the following VB.NET code (but for each loops are in most languages, thus the language-agnostic tag):

```
  Public Function VerifyServiceName(ByRef sMachineName As String, ByRef sServiceName As String) As Boolean
    Dim asServices As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController() = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices(sMachineName)
    Dim bVerified As Boolean = False
    For Each sService In asServices
      If sService.DisplayName = sServiceName Then bVerified = True
    Next
    Return bVerified
  End Function
```

If I have X number of services to loop through, and my service name is  #3. Is it better to have multiple `return` statements or an `exit for`? Or is there a more efficient way of writing this function?

I know that the time difference between looping X times and looping through 3 times could be marginal for what I am doing, but I always have performance on the brain.

Comment: What is an `exit for`? Is that like a `break`?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137115/are-multiple-return-points-from-a-method-good-or-bad

Comment: @Ignacio - Exit For jumps out of the for loop early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement) about the subject. I guess I am not that proficient at searching.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe having one `return` at the bottom is far more readable and easier to debug than if you have `return` statements everywhere, as you can never tell when the function is going to exit so you end up putting breakpoints on every `return` statement instead of just once at the end, for example.

I think it's all down to preference though, as there are valid arguments for both ways.

Comment: I didn't know if there was a standard way of handling the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would never use a goto as the target of another goto, so if there's some additional processing at the end of the function, use "break / Exit For", otherwise just return early.  Otherwise you end up with lines that mean "return" but say "break"... that doesn't help maintainability.